# Run robot test file with txt extension lead to Expected at least 1 argument, got 0 ERROR

Tags: python, robotframework

I try to run run `robot` test file with `.txt` extension with this command:

```
 robot -t C:\\test.txt`
```

And got this error:

> [ ERROR ] Expected at least 1 argument, got 0.

So i try to specifie the suite file as well:

```
robot -t C:\\test.txt` -s C:\\suite.txt
```

And got same error

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to give the test case name after -t and before test file.

E.g., I have a file example.robot:

```
*** Test Cases ***
TestA
    Log    A

TestB
    Log    B
```

If I want to run only TestA, I type `robot -t TestA example.robot`.

More info here: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#by-test-suite-and-test-case-names

And please edit your answer to exclude extra ` characters.

Comment: What is this TestA ? this is my .txt file ? and what is this example.robot file ? i dont have .robot file

Comment: If you want to run the whole file, just type:

`robot C:\\test.txt`

Comment: -t or --test flag is for selecting a specific test case in your test suite.

Answer (score 1):

The `-t` option specifies the name of a test, not the path of a file. If you want to run an entire file, you don't need the `-t` option:

```
robot C:/test.txt
```

If you want to run only one specific test inside that file, you can use the `-t` option to specify the test name. _You still must tell robot what file(s) to run`.

```
robot -t "Name of a test case"  C:/test.txt
```